# How to pass a function as a parameter in a performance.now function call?

Tags: performance, ecmascript-6, export, performance-testing, es6-modules

I am trying to refactor a performance function I wrote. I separated this function into its own file and I am importing it into a file with the function I want to test.

However, when I call the performance function and pass in twoSum with the parameters, I get an error of `performance.now is not a function`.

When I console.log `fn` from the performance function, I only get the output of twoSum, not the function itself.

```js
import performance from './performance.js'

const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
  let res = []
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if ((nums[i] + nums[j] === target) & (i !== j)) {
        res.push([i, j])
      }
    }
  }
  return res[0]
}

performance(twoSum([2, 5, 5, 11], 10)) // performance.now is not a function
```

```js
export default function  performance(fn) {
  let t0 = performance.now() //start time
  fn() //the function we need to measure
  let t1 = performance.now() //end time
  t1 - t0

  let avgTime = []
  const executions = 1_000_000
  for (let i = 0; i < executions; i++) {
    avgTime.push(t1 - t0)
  }
  return (avgTime.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / executions).toFixed(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an imported `performance` symbol and `function performance() {...}` in the same scope and have access to both as they will conflict so you have to change the name of one of the two so they don't conflict.

Change the name of your local `performance()` function to `perf()` as it is overriding/hiding the `performance` object that contains `performance.now()` like this:

```
export default function perf(fn) {
  let t0 = performance.now() //start time
  fn() //the function we need to measure
  let t1 = performance.now() //end time
  t1 - t0

  let avgTime = []
  const executions = 1_000_000
  for (let i = 0; i < executions; i++) {
    avgTime.push(t1 - t0)
  }
  return (avgTime.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / executions).toFixed(4)
}
```

Then, you would use the import the symbol `perf` when you use this module.

---

Or, you could also change the name of the `performance` object that you import from the system to a different local symbol name like this:

```
import { performance as perf } from 'perf_hooks';


export default function performance(fn) {
  let t0 = perf.now() //start time
  fn() //the function we need to measure
  let t1 = perf.now() //end time
  t1 - t0

  let avgTime = []
  const executions = 1_000_000
  for (let i = 0; i < executions; i++) {
    avgTime.push(t1 - t0)
  }
  return (avgTime.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / executions).toFixed(4)
}
```